# How to set text color in submit button?

Tags: html, css, button, submit-button

I tried to change the color of the text in the submit button type but, I don't know why I am not able to change it.

```css
.button {
  width: 105px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('tiny.gif');
  line-height: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Geneva, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  <!--font-weight: bold;
  -->text-transform: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.button:hover {
  background-image: url('tiny_.gif');
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Fetch" class="button" />
```

I was getting a problem when I tried to change the color of the submit button.

Comment: "Getting problems" -- this does't help us at all.  What are you expecting to have happen?  What is actually happening?  Are there any messages in your console log?  I added `background-color: red` to your `:hover` and the button changed colors when I moused over.  Perhaps `tiny_.gif` isn't loading?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

```css
.button
{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" value="Fetch" class="button"/>
```

Answer (score 24):

you try this:

```
<input type="submit" style="font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger; color: teal; background-color: #FFFFC0; border: 3pt ridge lightgrey" value=" Send Me! ">
```

Comment: Inline styles are not a good idea when an external stylesheet is available.

Comment: it's very good idea for poor css-ed pages, and for test how page will be rendered. for full css-ed pages this should be moved to external css file.

Answer (score 7):

```
<button id="fwdbtn" style="color:red">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this CSS:

```
color: red;
```

that's all.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same thought of wanting to change the text color rather than the button color itself to a different color. Here's what you can do:

```css
button {
    color: black; /* This is for the font color of the button */
    background-color: aqua; /* This is for the color of the button */
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
.btn{
    font-size: 20px;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your solution, only code is a bit hard to undestand correctly the answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

```
<input type = "button" style ="background-color:green"/>
```

Comment: OP wants to change text color of a submit and you provide him with an inline style (=bad practice) changing background color of a button. This doesn't help much...