# How do I change the color of text in my button?

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple website and most of them have a top bar. While I was designing one with buttons for each section I came across the problem that i cannot change the font color of my buttons. Can someone help? I know how to with a div but not with a button. Here is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            button {
                outline: none;
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin-top:5px;
                color:#DEDEDE;
                border:1px solid black;
                height:30px;
                margin-left: 15px;
                margin-right: 15px
            }
            #bThree {
                margin-right: 550px;
            }
            #topBar {
                border-radius: 5px;
                height: 40px;
                width:100%;
                background:blue;
                background-color:#20AB53;  
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="topBar">
            <button id="bOne">About</button>
            <button id="bTwo">Home</button>
            <button id="bThree">Log In</button>
            <button id="bFour">Sign Up</button>
            <button id="bFive">Contact</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
button {
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: #DEDEDE;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
#bThree {
  margin-right: 550px;
}
#topBar {
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  background-color: #20AB53;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
  <button id="bOne">About</button>
  <button id="bTwo">Home</button>
  <button id="bThree">Log In</button>
  <button id="bFour">Sign Up</button>
  <button id="bFive">Contact</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You have `color:#DEDEDE;` on `button` which is working fine to me.

Comment: It [works perfectly well](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dLwmhsdx/), you just need to use a colour with more contrast, [such as #999](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dLwmhsdx/1/), or darker.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set text color in submit button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471132/how-to-set-text-color-in-submit-button)

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/zakCa/1/

```
.button {
    color: green;
}
```