# How to change text color in button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the button text for 'New Service Request' to white. Please advise.

```css
.btn-info { background: #0066cc; border: none; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 18px; padding: 10px 20px; }

.btn-info:hover{

background: #003366;

transition: 0.5s background;}
```

```html
<button class="btn-info"> <a href="LINK">New Service Request</a></button>
```

Comment: Do you want change text color white when mouse hover?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set text color in submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12471132/how-to-set-text-color-in-submit-button)

Comment: @chandu.komati I don't think that's related as their issue that it is a `button` with an `a` nested within it. Targetting the `button` with CSS won't modify the font-color as per the linked example. The only answer is to target the `a` within the `button` using CSS.

Comment: your HTML is invalid, `a` cannot be inside a button element

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the color of the a tag within the button to white.

Example:

```css
.btn-info {
  background: #0066cc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  background: #003366;
  transition: 0.5s background;
}

.btn-info a {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-info"> <a href="LINK">New Service Request</a></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to target `.button-info a` to change the color of your text to white.

```html
<style>

.btn-info { background: #0066cc; border: none; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 18px; padding: 10px 20px; }

.btn-info a, .btn-info:hover {
  color: white;
}

.btn-info:hover{

background: #003366;

transition: 0.5s background;}

</style>

<button class="btn-info"> <a href="LINK">New Service Request</a></button>
```

It's worth noting too that your HTML is invalid, the nested structure `<button><a></a></button>` is not accepted, and can be checked by a [Markup Validation Service](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input). See the error below:

> Error: The element `a` must not appear as a descendant of the `button` element.

A valid and more succinct version of your code is as follows:

```html
<style>
  .btn-info {
    background: #0066cc;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .btn-info:hover {
    background: #003366;
    transition: 0.5s background;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

</style>

<input type="button" class="btn-info" onclick="location.href='http://google.com';" value="Google" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your class `button-info` to white You can do something like this. Hope it helps

```css
.btn-info { 
background: #0066cc; 
border: none; 
border-radius: 5px; 
font-size: 14px; 
padding: 10px 10px; }

.btn-info a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-info:hover{
background-color: #003366;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-info"> <a href="LINK">New Service Request</a></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the a tag altogether, and give the hover state of the button a rule of `cursor: pointer`:

```css
.btn-info {
  background: #0066cc;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.btn-info:hover {
  background: #003366;
  transition: 0.5s background;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-info">New Service Request</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```html
.btn-info
{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:green;
}

<button class="btn-info"> <a href="LINK">New Service Request</a></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You should target the  inside .button-info class to change the color of your text.**

Answer (score 0):

```
try this code: 

    .btn-info { background: #0066cc; border: none; border-radius: 3px; font-size: 18px; padding: 10px 20px; }

    .btn-info:hover{
    color: #fff;
    background: #003366; 

    transition: 0.5s background;}



    <button class="btn-info" href="LINK">New Service Request</button>
```